# Merge single array objects by value and preserve duplicates in sub array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, merge, unique

I have the following (simplified) array:

```
$myArray = array(
   0=> array( 
      'userid' => '12',
      'favcolor' => 'green'
   ),
   1=> array( 
      'userid' => '62',
      'favcolor' => 'orange'
   ),
   2=> array( 
      'userid' => '12',
      'favcolor' => 'red'
   ),
   3=> array( 
      'userid' => '62',
      'favcolor' => 'blue'
   ),
)
```

I would like to merge the array by the common userid value present and keep the fav colour information. Other methods i've tried only keep the first favcolor value from the array. Seems simple enough, but not been able to find an quick solution for this.

**Expected output:**

```
$myArray = array(
   0=> array( 
      'userid' => '12',
      'favcolor' => array('green', 'red')
   ),
   1=> array( 
      'userid' => '62',
      'favcolor' => array('orange', 'blue')
   ),
)
```

Is this possible without working with another array to compare against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we are using simple `foreach`  for merging and achieving expected result, By using `userid` of this array as the `key`. here we are using `array_values` to remove those key.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/783751)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$myArray = array(
   0=> array( 
      'userid' => '12',
      'favcolor' => 'green'
   ),
   1=> array( 
      'userid' => '62',
      'favcolor' => 'orange'
   ),
   2=> array( 
      'userid' => '12',
      'favcolor' => 'red'
   ),
   3=> array( 
      'userid' => '62',
      'favcolor' => 'blue'
   ),
);
$result=array();
foreach($myArray as $value)
{
    //check for previous existence of key in resultant array
    //if key not exist then put value on that key and using favcolor as array
    if(!isset($result[$value["userid"]]))of key in a array.
    {
        $result[$value["userid"]]=array("userid"=>$value["userid"],"favcolor"=>array($value["favcolor"]));
    }
    //if key already exists then just adding favcolor values to that key
    else
    {
        $result[$value["userid"]]["favcolor"][]=$value["favcolor"];
    }
}
print_r(array_values($result));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [userid] => 12
            [favcolor] => Array
                (
                    [0] => green
                    [1] => red
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [userid] => 62
            [favcolor] => Array
                (
                    [0] => orange
                    [1] => blue
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @Rizier123 I am adding explanation

Comment: Thanks Sahil, had to modify slightly as was getting the following error:  "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array". changed code to use $value->userid rather that $value["userid"] and works perfect.

Comment: @JackCallow I voted up your post as it seams useful to me... welcome.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply do as follows

```
// Creating an array for result
foreach($myArray as $ar){
    if(!isset($aa[$ar['userid']])) $aa[$ar['userid']] = [];
    if(!in_array($ar['favcolor'],$aa[$ar['userid']])) $aa[$ar['userid']][] = $ar['favcolor'];
}

// Designing it according to result
foreach($aa as $arr=>$val)
    $last[] =  ['userid'=>$arr,'favcolor'=>$val];

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($last);
```

Comment: we can also have this on a single array, but for the sake of simplicity i have done it through this..